# Is there any Celeryd or Celery (for Django/Python) type altenative for Symfony 2 framework

Tags: php, python, django, symfony, celery

I am a big fan of [Celery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celery_Task_Queue) for executing scheduled tasks in Django. I am now using [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) 2 and see that it is almost similar to Django framework.

I wonder if there is something similar to Celery in Symfony for scheduling task queues.

Comment: Which message broker are you using?

Comment: I don't know if we can use message broker with symfony? can we?

Comment: You can use Celery and webhook tasks, this way you expose your tasks as a web page in PHP and the worker then calls the URLs asynchronously: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/remote-tasks.html

Comment: Symfony 2 similar to Django? ... Maybe the templating language!? :/

Answer (score 0):

Celery is providing a simple layer to use messaging. It makes the task of building async services easy. Interestingly the concept is not new. It is already available in form of standard protocol like AMQP. Documentation available at

http://php.net/manual/en/book.amqp.php

Although I can't vouch for it but potentially you could hookup PHP and Python code as publisher and subscriber, thus using Celery for doing the task while PHP code could issue it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple implementation of Queues, based in Redis.

https://github.com/mmoreram/rsqueue-bundle

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Beanstalkd.

You can use **LeezyPheanstalkBundle** or **PheanstalkBundle**.

- http://www.github.com/armetiz/LeezyPheanstalkBundle
- http://www.github.com/drymek/PheanstalkBundle

or you can check other clients:

- https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/client-libraries